# Setup cost effective CMTS for testing purpose

Tags: cable-modem

Is there any way to setup my own cable networks very cost effective for testing purpose?

For example, PCI card for [CMTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem_termination_system) and using Linux server. I found http://www.c9networks.com/ sold PCI card for CMTS, but as I know they stopped this product.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try watching eBay for a used Cadant C3. They're pretty small and not too pricey, so, not too bad for home usage.